# How to make openapi codegen generate a client that supports XML in request and response body?

Tags: python, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

There is a REST API which is described with OpenAPI. Each of the methods send responses and accept requests in XML format. I tried generating python clients for this API with openapi, but none supported XML.
I have tried using different generators: python, python-prior and python-legacy and 3 libraries: urllib, asyncio, tornado, but this didn`t help.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

set the config "withXml" as "true" in open api generator config options

Comment: This doesn`t work for Python